# PowerShell Script "&" "&&" "||" Operators

Tags: powershell

I am new to PowerShell scripting. I have been given the task to understand what a PowerShell script is doing.

I am stuck at following line:

```
& $basePath\CPAU.exe -u $($sqlUser.UserName) -p $(ConvertTo-UnsecureString $sqlUser.Password) -ex "cmd /c (sqlcmd $($sqlArgs -join ' ') > $outputFile && echo TRUE > SUCCESS) || echo TRUE > FAILURE" -wait -nowarn -hide
```

It feels like the script is trying to execute some sort of sql command. However, I am not sure of starting "&" symbol.

Also, could CPAU.exe be an external in basepath? And what do `-p`, `-u`, and `-ex` enforce?

Next line:

```
if (!(Test-Path .\SUCCESS))
{
    #some more code
}
```

In above if statement, what does `.\SUCCESS` mean? Doesn't `Test-Path` operate on some sort of path to test whether it exists or not?

Comment: `-u` username, `-p` password and `-ex` is probably execute?

Comment: Thanks, could you write an answer explaining whole line? I still don't get what is "||" for and TRUE>FAILURE?

Comment: Kindly give the down vote reason please.

Comment: I'm not very good at powershell, just pointed out some things. The `||` is an `or` condition.

Comment: No, or is written as "-OR" in powershell

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `||` still stands for an `OR` condition in this case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64881/discussion-between-nitinsh99-and-krister-andersson).

Comment: It is an or for the cmd session that is being started.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`&` is the PowerShell [call operator](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh847732.aspx), which *"runs a command, script, or script block"*. In your case it's running the external command `CPAU.exe` located in `$basePath` with the parameters `-u`, `-p`, `-ex`, `-wait`, `-nowarn`, and `-hide`. That command runs another command (the argument of the parameter `-ex`):

```
cmd /c (sqlcmd $($sqlArgs -join ' ') > $outputFile && echo TRUE > SUCCESS) || echo TRUE > FAILURE
```

The above uses `cmd.exe` (the Windows Command Prompt) to run `sqlcmd $($sqlArgs -join ' ')`, redirect its output to the file `$outputFile`, and write "TRUE" to either the file `SUCCESS` if the command succeeded or to the file `FAILURE` otherwise.

`||` and `&&` are `cmd` operators for command chaining. `||` means "run the next command if the previous command failed". `&&` means "run the next command if the previous command succeeded".

Answer (score 0):

```
& $basePath\CPAU.exe -u $($sqlUser.UserName) -p $(ConvertTo-UnsecureString $sqlUser.Password) -ex "cmd /c (sqlcmd $($sqlArgs -join ' ') > $outputFile && echo TRUE > SUCCESS) || echo TRUE > FAILURE" -wait -nowarn -hide
```

This is some Powershell code, calling the executable CPAU.exe stored in $basePath passing a username and password and making it execute some CMD code:

cmd /c (sqlcmd $($sqlArgs -join ' ') > $outputFile && echo TRUE > SUCCESS) || echo TRUE > FAILURE

The cmd executes a SQL command given some predefined $sqlArgs, joined by a space. The whole command is redirected to $outputFile which is also expected to be predefined.

If the output of the command AND the ability to Echo TRUE on the CMD console is true, a file called SUCCESS is created receiving the redirected output. Else, if something fails but the echo TRUE happens, a FAILURE file is created.

The whole thing waits for everything to be complete, gives no warning and ...hides....

Whoever wrote this, needs a vacation.